# Mongodb database design

Tags: mongodb

I got users, they can create activities and users have friends and each user should be able to get all activities from their friends, a single activity can have multiple users.

```
Users -> _id, name, friendList
Activity -> _id, description, date, involvedUsers
```

So an example document would be:

```
"User theo": 1, theo, array(mike, rutger, tijmen)
"User mike": 2, mike, array(theo, rutger, tijmen)

Activity x: 1, 'having fun with friends', {{todaydatetime}}, array(1, 2)
Activity y: 2, 'going out', {{saturdaydatetime}}, array(1, 2)
```

So now if "theo" logs in, he has to get that Mike is "going to have fun with friends" same if Mike logs in.

And if they select saturday as date, Mike will get that Theo is going out, and Theo would get the activity that Mike is going out.

How can I accomplish this, I know it's pretty easy in MySql with joins etc, but how can I get all the activities of the users "friendlist" and filtered by a certain date, so for example give me all activities that are happening saturday.

Comment: So, why do you want to use mongodb? Use MySQL, you know how to do it there.

Comment: That was not my question, I have to use MongoDb.

Comment: Scalability that's why, don't wanna go into a discussion whether it is or MySql is or not, my question is how it can be done.

Comment: MongoDB is not good for everything!

Comment: I didn't say that, but since I'm using MongoDb I noticed a very big improvement in performance, it is easier to code in and scalable with sharding.

Comment: @MikeVercoelen: it may very well turn out so that after you finally make it work, you'll find yourself with a schema that doesn't scale. Worst of both worlds! But I'll keep an eye on this question :-)

Comment: @randomKek did you end up using the answer below or finding a better schema/query? If so can you please share?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want something like (this is totally untested), and the others are right, if you have too big of arrays (thousands) for your friends lists and your involved, it will probably cause scaling problems:

```
collection users:
{
  _id: objid, 
  name: "theo", 
  friends: [objid, objid, objid] /* these are user object ids */
}

collection activities:
{
  _id: objid, 
  desc: "having fun with friends", 
  date: new Date(), 
  involved: [objid, objid, objid] /* these are user object ids */
}
```

I would do ensureIndex on date and involved. See here for more information on indexing array values: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Multikeys

```
db.activities.ensureIndex({date:1});
db.activities.ensureIndex({involved:1});
```

So to select the users involved in an activity you would do (from the shell):

```
var start_date = new Date(2012, 1, 14);
var end_date = new Date(2012, 1, 15);
var friends = db.users.findOne(_id: objid for user).friends;
var activities = db.activities.find(
   {
     date: {$gte : start_date},
     date: {$lte : end_date},
     involved : {$in : friends}
   });
```

Comment: I understand about the friendlist, but I just need MongoDb also because of geocoding functionality and performance in mongodb. What would you advise me MySql?

Comment: I would probably use mongodb either way. If you end up needing to use a different schema to support more friends or more involved, then you can break it out into different collections--it will take more lookups to get your answers, though.

Comment: shouldn't it be `$lt` in the date selection, to get only one day (otherwise from what I understand it selects the day after, too)?

Answer (score 0):

If you have to use MongoDB (which isn't a bad choice) you will have to read the docs.

For this particular situation, you are interested in searching within an array:

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Dot+Notation+%28Reaching+into+Objects%29

Comment: But how would I structure my documents?